# Node Js Version not avaiable on shared server

Tags: node.js, next.js, tailwind-css, hosting, next.js13

I'm currently trying to create a website using Node Js app, tailwind css and Next.Js. I've gotten the app to work locally on my computer using Git Bash, the version it works on is 18.17.0 and higher which is what is written in the output below. The hosting server uses cPanel but it only supports up to 14.21.2. So I searched online and read that I could use NVM (https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm) and I installed it successfully, changed the version of node to 14.21.2. But when I try to run it through the server online I get this error:

```
> next dev

You are using Node.js 14.21.2. For Next.js, Node.js version >= v18.17.0 is required.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @ dev: `next dev`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @ dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

I've tried installing NVM on the server and I did successfully but when I try to update Node JS but it doesnt change. Ive tried removing the node modules and package.lock.json file and changing the version of node in the engines field to 14.21.2 and the version of next in the dependencies to a downgraded version compatible with node 14.21.2 and reinstalled npm but nothing has worked.

Answer (score 1):

Your next js and node js version sre conflicting. You need node 18.17.0 or above for using the current version of next js you are using. You can downgrade next js.. but its not advisable as it will introduce some breaking changes.

To downgrade :

in pacakge.json there will be dependencies , change them according to your usage ( Next.js 12 is supported with your node version )

```
 "dependencies": 
{ "next": "^12.0.0",
 // other dependencies... 
}
```

then run `npm install next@12.0.0` then run
`npm i`

Comment: The main issue is that I already bought the shared hosting thinking that the version of node js would be supported. Is there a method to downgrade next js? I had trouble finding sources. Would I need to also downgrade tailwind and react?

Comment: check updated solution. mark verified or upvote if found helpful